# How to send an unknown number of filter values to DRF with React? GET or POST?

Tags: django, reactjs, axios

I am building a filtering system where you can filter products by brand and category. The user selects the filters in a React Application and this triggers a request to the backend API (Django Rest Framework - DRF) that is either GET or Post. Ideally Django would receive the filter names as value it can iterate over.

**I am quite lost on how to achieve this.**

A GET request would be possible. But in order for DRF to work with the request it needs to have a uri-format as such:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/filter/?categories=proviant&categories=multipower&brands=kellogs
```

I could then use a view like this to grab the values.

```
class ProductFilterListView(APIView):

    def get(self, request):
        for el in request.GET.getlist('categories'):
            print(el)
        return Response('')
```

This is quite a challenge since axios (library for making JS requests) does not have an option to format the url according to the requirements of DRF. So this feels very wrong and very manual and is hardly a "good" solution (?)

The other way would be to use a post request. But then again, I have never used a post request for something that does not have a serializer or a form on the Django side. So, I would not know how to validate the incoming post data and convert it to a format Django can work with.

**What would be the "right" way to approach this?**

**UPDATE:::**

I found that axios has a paramsSerializer option that allows to format the uri into the format I needed. Here is a snipped of the solution. So I guess the GET request in the way to go ... **(?)**

```
try {
            const res = await axios.get(`${baseURL}product/filter/`, {
                params: {
                    categories: filterArr
                }, paramsSerializer: (params) => {
                    return Qs.stringify(params, {arrayFormat: 'repeat'})
                  },
            })
        } catch(e) {

        }
```

Comment: In axios the url argument is just a string, why would it be difficult to do in that format? Even if your categories on the front end was an array then it would be pretty easy to turn that into a string that you could append to the url.

Comment: yeah, you are right. It is not hard at all but pretty verbose and it involves a lot of very weird string manipulation. Usually (100% of times) when I do stuff like that - I am doing it wrong. Same here: (as it turns out) axios has a paramsSerializer option which formats the uri in the desired format.

Answer (score 0):

List of values can be passed through the URL as parameters like this:

```
http://localhost:8000/?categories=first,second,third
```

Axios takes a `params` argument when you post, get, etc. ([documentation](https://github.com/axios/axios#using-applicationx-www-form-urlencoded-format)):

```
const params = new URLSearchParams();
params.append('categories', [1, 2, 4, 76]);
axios.post('/foo', params);
```

Comment: A comma-separated list isn't recognised by Django as a list of items but as a single string. The only way recognised by Django (that can be retrieved by `getlist()`) is repeating the key multiple times: `categories=first&categories=second`.

Comment: hey, thanks for the help. Yeah, I see there are many formats (hardly standardised) to send arrays via the url. As far as I know DRF only supports the format I mentioned in the initial post. "?categories=proviant&categories=multipower". You can achieve the desired format with the code I wrote in the "UPDATE" above.

Comment: maybe on a sidenote ... are there security concerns with this? would it be possible to inject code via these GET parameters?

Comment: Inject them where? A GET request shouldn't be modifying any data. An alternative to `getlist()` could be `categories = request.GET.get('categories').split(',')`

Comment: basically the same as sql injection. Just pass code as a GET parameter that makes an sql query for example. I would assume that there is some inherent security already build in ... but I think I will research it.